# Docker couchbase cbbackup/cbtransfer/cbrestore tools

Tags: docker, backup, couchbase, restore

I've used docker to install couchbase on my ubuntu machine using (https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/). The docker run query is as follows:

```
docker run -d --name db -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 -v /home/dockercontent/couchbase:/opt/couchbase/var couchbase
```

Everything works perfectly fine. My application connects, I'm able to insert/update and query the couchbase. Now, I'm looking to debug a situation wherein the couchbase is on my co-developers machine who also has the same installation i.e., couchbase on docker using the above link. For achieving this, I wanted to run cbbackup on his installation. To achieve this, I run the following command which is a variation of the above link:

```
bash -c "clear && docker exec -it couch-db sh"
```

Can anyone please help me with the location of /opt/couchbase/bin in this setup? I believe this is where I can get access to "cbbackup", "cbrestore" and "cbtransfer" which I can then use to backup and restore data from my colleague's machine.

Thanks,
Abhi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run the command

`docker run -d --name db -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 -v /home/dockercontent/couchbase:/opt/couchbase/var couchbase`

you're pulling a [docker image](https://docs.docker.com/glossary/?term=image) and spawning a [docker container](https://docs.docker.com/glossary/?term=container).

Please read more about Docker and containerization.

In order to run `cbbackup` you need to log into your docker container.

Follow these steps:

- Retrieve the container-id:

  `$ docker ps -a`

  Look for the `CONTAINER ID` for `IMAGE NAME`=`couchbase`
- Login to the container using the command:

  `$ docker exec -it <container-id> bash`
- Go to the directory : `/opt/couchbase/bin` using:

  `$ cd /opt/couchbase/bin`

You'll find `cbbackup` binary in this directory.

Comment: how can I copy this backup to my home folder?